# Erro no Reactive Native ao gerar app Android

Tags: javascript, java, android, angularjs, react

**Estou executando os comandos:**

```
react-native init AwesomeProject
cd AwesomeProject
react-native start
```

**E depois esse comando:**

```
react-native run-android
```

**O erro que aparece:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como corrigir esse erro ??

Comment: Relativamente ao primeiro problema, EPERM, normalmente se tiveres as variáveis de ambiente bem configuradas, deves utilizar a linha de comandos como administrador o que deverá corrigir o problema.

Relativamente ao segundo erro, podes anexar os resultados do comando 'adb devices'?
Aparenta ser uma questão de não teres um emulator ou telefone/tablet ligado/disponivel no momento.

Comment: correto. Com a inicialização do Emular. conseguir corrigir o segundo erro. Quanto ao primeiro foi apensa configurar as variáveis de ambiente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Erro foi corrigido configurando as variáveis de ambiente e atualizando o JDK e JRE.

2 Segundo erro foi corrigido apenas inicializando o emulador Android(no caso do ambiente android)